# `docker compose create ecs` without user input

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am looking for a way to run `docker compose create ecs` without having to manually select where it gets AWS credentials from (as it's being run from a build agent).

In the following AWS blog it shows it being used with a flag `--from-env` (which is exactly what I want), however that flag doesn't seem to actually exist, either in the official docs, or by trial and error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automated-software-delivery-using-docker-compose-and-amazon-ecs/

Comment: It appears the flag DOES exist, at least on my local machine, it's just not available on the build agent, even though they are running the same docker version... but the build agent is linux, and locally I am running Windows

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a known issue

https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11845

You have to enable experimental support for the docker cli in Linux to create an ecs context :S